# Simulate docker exec -it contid bash with python, while being able to send commands via python

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, pty

I would like to be able to simulate the interactive mode with Python.

For example, if I write

docker exec -it c2 bash, followed by a cd /home, I will be able to see what I am doing and where I am. I tried to do so several times and in a several ways via Python, but the best I can do is just forward a command to a docker container from a parent container - without any feedback on what's actually happening on the screen.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import pty

master,slave = pty.openpty()

print(master)
print(slave)
p = Popen(["docker", "exec", "-i", "c2" ,"/bin/bash"], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate("cd /home;mkdir 1231321".encode())
```

This code works, with no output. Also, the script automatically exits the container, without me sending "exit" command, which is not something that I want.

I'm curious, if it's possible to do such task, via a python script?

Thanks.

Comment: `Popen.communicate()` returns the output. You can use `print(..)` to show it on screen. If you want the user to be able to type more commands, then it's your responsibility to read data from the user and relay it to the process.

Comment: What's your end goal with this setup?  That sequence of commands almost looks like you're trying to write a Dockerfile but inside some other running process.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I have a large amount of servers to maintain, and I would like to automatize that process. Do you think that Dockerfile could help me out with automatizing that process?

For example, I want to create directory in all of 100 docker containers and do a git pull. I would also like to do that via "-it" flag, just for the sake of curiosity. 

I'm struggling with pseudo terminals.

Preferrably, what I would like to do is 

1 ) Open a container with -it flag
2) Write some commands
3 ) Exit
4 ) Repeat, via for loop.

Comment: @thatotherguy - in the case above, if i print p.communicate(), it returns (None, None)

Comment: That task sounds a lot like you're trying to attach debuggers to your production systems and do live code updates inside the running processes.  That's not a standard way to use Docker.  Typically to take an update, you'd build a new image with your updated code, test that image, then delete your existing containers and recreate them with new images.  The `docker exec` debugging tool is not part of this workflow.

Comment: I'm new to using Docker, so your comments are greatly appreciate David. The thing is, that each of these containers should have a different IP, which I had to manually setup, and if I redo the containers from a new image, the settings from 1 container will be kept and I would need to manually reconfigure the IP addresses.

If there's an option where I would be able to only make changes to the filesystem, while keeping the network configuration, then that would be a viable option.

In the other case, it seems to me that I'd need to change stuff inside containers via docker exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I wanted to do in the beginning, leaving answer below since it may be helpful to someone.

In order to simulate interactive mode, I used python pexpect library. Following format should do the trick.

```
p = pexpect.spawn(cmd)
p.expect(/regex/)
p.sendline("what you'd like to send")
```

Repeat.